# Excel 2013 - Fill in numbers from 2000 - 65000 without using the drag to fill handle mouse method

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I need to fill in numbers from 2000 to 65000 in Excel 2013 and using the fill handle and dragging is a very long process.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Enter "2000" in A1. The, enter the formula A2=A1+1, and copy this formula to A3 until A65000 by first selecting A3 then holding **shift**, and scrolling with the mouse to A65000, and clicking on the cell, then releasing shift. Paste the formula. This will give you what you want.

If you would like to convert the formula to values afterwards, select all copy again, paste as values.

Comment: And if you don't want to use a mouse, select A2, hold *Shift*, press *End*, press *Arrow Down*, release *Shift*. Then paste. Although in newer versions of Excel, this will fill more than1,000,000 rows...

Comment: This will not work for this specific question on **Excel 2013**, because it allows 1,048,576 rows.

Comment: Yes you are right, that's why I didn't post it as an answer. It may help others who have a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set first cell to your start value.
2. Set the cell below it to CellAbove + 1.
3. Click to select the second cell.
4. Scroll down and shift click the end cell.
5. Ctrl-D (Fill, Down)
6. Ctrl-C (Copy)
7. Ctrl-Alt-V (Paste Special)
8. Select "Values", click OK

It's a method the [Brute Squad](http://karifry.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/brute-squad12.jpg) would use, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is a macro using VBA:

```
Sub megafiller()
    firstvalue = 2000
    lastvalue = 65000
    firstcellrow = 1
    firstcellcolumn = 1
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    thisrow = firstcellrow
    For j = firstvalue To lastvalue
        wks.Cells(thisrow, firstcellcolumn) = j
        thisrow = thisrow + 1
    Next j
    theend = MsgBox("Finished", vbInformation)
End Sub
```

Open Macro/VBA, under *ThisWorkbook* insert a module and paste the code on the right side. Run it and that's all. With the variables you can modify the start (200) and end (65000) values. Also you can modify the start cell. For this code is A1 (`firstcellrow=1` and `firstcellcolumn=1`).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to everyone for helping me out.  I also found another way that I had never seen before.  Using the Fill button on the Home Tab in the Editing Group and selecting Series I selected Columns and Linear and put in the Stop Value of 65,000 and clicked OK.  That worked great!

Again, thanks to everyone for taking the time to help me out.  It is much appreciated.